# Translating C Code to Mips Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Quick question. I'm looking to translate this C code into MIPS assembly language:
    f=g-A[B[4]]
I can use any registers to place the variables so I used the following:
$s1=f, $s2=g, $s3=A, $s4=B, $t0=B[4], $t1=A[B[4]]

Here is the code I have tried so far but I am not sure if it is correct or not:

```
lw $t0, 16($s4)
add $t0, $t0, $s3
lw $t1, 0($t0)
sub $s1, $s2, $t1
```

Can you guys help me edit this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks fine to me

Comment: Your not sure if it is correct?  What is the correct output of the C code?  Now Assemble and run your MIPS code, do you get the same output?  If so, then it is correct!

Answer (score 1):

If you have some C code you can compile it to assembly using gcc

```
gcc-mipsel-linux-gnu -save-temps program.c
cat program.S
```

this assumes you have a mipsel [cross-]compiler installed, get one from

http://www.emdebian.org/crosstools.html

or

https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingCrossCompilers

Comment: He's posted a correct answer. I don't understand the mild hostility here.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do my homework. I have already written out an attempted answer. I am looking for either confirmation that it is correct or a possible step I can take to get going in the right direction. The link you posted will not help me learn at all but just give me the correct answer. That is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't scale the index of `A` by the size of the `A` elements.  You probably want to multiply `$t0` by 4 before adding `$s3`.

Comment: Shift left by 2 uses fewer transistors.  (Given the size of a flow-multiply array, a multiply has to cost in power...even if it doesn't cost in time.)